# Why is the first element of numpy array set to one after processing?

Tags: python, numpy

In the loop below, 4-by-4 arrays are loaded from .npz files and stored in the second two dimensions of an array, `examples`.

```
    k=0
    files_in_dir = os.listdir('../FGSMGenerated/eps{}/case{}'.format(ep,CASE))
        for files in files_in_dir:
            if files.endswith('.npz'):
                data = np.load(os.path.join('../FGSMGenerated/eps{}/case{}'.format(ep,CASE),files))
                array = data['features']
                examples[k,:,:,0,0]=array
                k += 1
```

However, when accessing an individual 4-by-4 array from `examples` with

```
temp_array = examples[idx,:,:,0,0]
```

the first element of `temp_array` (ie `temp_array[0,0]`) is always 1, even though this is not the element in the [0,0] position of the original array.
However, every other element of `temp_array` is consistent with the original array.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What's the `dtype` of your arrays (original and target)?  Is it only the first byte, or all bytes that are wrong?

Comment: Can you show us a version which replicates your problem, with say, a few 4x4 arrays? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: both np.float32 and it is only the first element that is wrong.

Comment: I will update my question with the actual code because maybe the problem lies outside of the general case that I made up

Comment: I changed the dimension to 4x4. and you can imagine there are only 2 examples being looped over if you like.

Comment: Yes. feel free to minus one me if you don't know the answer. That is clearly outlined in the stack exchange guidelines.

Comment: You don't give us enough information to recreate the problem.  With a normal initialization of `examples` and a made up (4,4) `array`, this does not happen.  Obviously we can't `load` your files and get the actual `data` array.

Comment: Is there any other code between the code block you've shown us and fetching the first element of the array? Maybe some sneaky reassignment of said element? Like hpaulj said, with only the code you've given us there should be no problem. We need a [minimal, complete AND verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're running into that problem, but you should take a look at the methods `np.tile` and `np.repeat`, if every slice of the 3D array is the same, and `np.stack` and its friends if they're different. These are for exactly this purpose, building larger arrays out of smaller ones.